# Twilio - Filtering call logs based on timestamp

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio

I am working in nodejs and this is my existing code, which is fetching all the twilio calls:

```
client = require("twilio")(accountSid, authToken);

client.calls.list({ });
```

I want to get twilio calls which were made between a start and end start. Something like this:

```
client.calls.list({ dateCreated: { $gt: start, $lt: end } });
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some starter code examples here:

Call Resource
https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call-resource

Node Example: "Read multiple Call resources and filter by 'after start' date"

Month starts at 0 (0 = January)

```
client.calls
      .list({
         startTimeAfter: new Date(Date.UTC(2020, 4, 15, 0, 0, 0)),
         endTimeBefore: new Date(Date.UTC(2020, 5, 18, 0, 0, 0)),
         status: 'completed',
         limit: 200
       })
      .then(calls => calls.forEach(c => console.log(c.dateCreated)))
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
```